# Unable to select a value from a dropdown: ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, dropdown

I am automating with Java selenium the entry of data of an user, but he has to select the State through a dropdown. I'm getting an exception error.

I have tried using all selectors:

```
drpState.selectByIndex(5);
drpState.selectByValue("CA");
drpState.selectByVisibleText("California");
```

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
            <label id="xstateLabel">@lang('messages.state')</label>
            <select class="form-control js-select" style="width: 100%" id="xstate" name="xstate">
                <option value=""> State </option>
                <option value="AL" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='AL'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='AK'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='AZ'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='AR'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='CA'){echo 'selected';} ?>>California</option>
                <option value="CO" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='CO'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT" <?php if(isset($usr->state) && $usr->state=='CT'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Connecticut</option>
                *
                *
                *
          </select>
```

I created the function:

```
public void select() {
    Select drpState = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("xstate")));

    drpState.selectByValue("CA");
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'PBX-WS2-SL2', ip: '10.30.10.54', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d24..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DAYANA~1.SIL\AppDa...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56255}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 75.0.3770.100, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 7b5fe4de6ccaace4b79ddee37685d7a2
```

Comment: FWIW: your chrome and chromedriver versions are mismatched.

Comment: Did you notice that your provided source says `DEselectByVisibleText`?

Comment: Have you tried clicking element with xpath `//select/option[@value='CA']`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("xstate")));

Select drpState = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("xstate")));

drpState.selectByValue("CA");
```

Comment: I continue getting an Error Execption. I can see that the select never opened, should it does it?
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: xstate (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)